# How to export a huge amount of data from Oracle SQL Developer in PSV Format and in multiple files

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a huge dataset comprising of about 600000000 rows. I need to export all these rows in pipe separated values format, and data should be in multiple files instead of 1 huge file, with each file containing 100000000 rows.

I tried exporting this file with right click --> Export --> Delimited --> Multiple files, but there is no option to specify number of rows in each file, and data is exported in .dsv format not .psv format.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: ".dsv" is just part of the file name. It's all ASCII text; just change the file name to "filename.psv". As for "multiple files" I think this only applies when exporting multiple tables: separate files for each table, not multiple files for one table. I don't know for sure, but if your source table is partitioned then maybe it would generate a separate file for each partition.

Comment: My table is not partitioned. Is there any way that I can export the data into multiple files?

Comment: You could add a where clause in the data selection and limit the output that way. You'd have to run separate exports for each segment and adjust your where clause each time. Base the filter on your primary key, if possible.

Comment: consider a plsql program that does exactly what you want, writing the file to the server using UTL_FILE...